# How to display non-English character correctly in db2cmd?

Tags: db2, db2-luw, encoding, unicode, client

On Db2 v11.5.7 on Linux/x86_64 I have a UTF-8 database.

Executing `db2 get db cfg for test1` returns:

```
 Database code page       = 1208
 Database code set        = UTF-8
```

On my Windows 10 computer in Putty I have set: *Window | Translation | Remote character set* to UTF-8. I can properly see non-English characters in Putty.

I have also installed DBeaver tool and I can also properly see non-English characters.

The problem I have is "db2cmd" tool.

In Putty remote connection I created tables and inserted one character:

```
db2 "connect to test1 user db2inst1 using db2inst1"
db2 "create table admin.test8 (id int not null generated always as identity, a varchar(20))"
db2 "insert into admin.test8 (a) values ('č')"
db2 "select id, a, hex(a) as hex_a from admin.test8 order by id"
```

Output of select statement is (which is correct):

[image]

If I do the same in DBeaver:

```
insert into admin.test8 (a) values ('č');
select id, a, hex(a) as hex_a from admin.test8 order by id;
```

I get:

[image]

Both Putty and DBeaver correctly inserts character in database.

Now saving the commands into UTF-8 encoding:

[image]

From db2cmd I check for the code page:

```
chcp
```

and output is:

```
Active code page: 1252
```

Execute commands:
db2 -tf a.sql

[image]

Output in column A is completely wrong. In ID=3 also HEX_A is completely wrong.

I tried several things like:

1. Changing: `chcp 65001`
2. `db2set DB2CODEPAGE=1208`

But in both cases I see the same result as last command.

If I try to connect with "-a" switch I get Db2 server code page is 1208 (utf-8) and Db2 client code page is 1252.

[image]

Now to configure db2cmd to properly handle the UTF-8 code-page?

Comment: What does `locale` return when you run it as the user that connects to the database?

Comment: Interesting question. Not an answer, but have you tried with PowerShell (not the same but close)? What about a local terminal from Mobaxterm or similar tool?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried to set the system default locale to UTF-8 (don't want to risk).
db2 clp on Windows doesn't work normally with terminal input and output.
But you may make it produce correct UTF-8 output into a file or accept correct UTF-8 input with the following.
It's important to run db2 terminate after setting DB2CODEPAGE.
True Type font must be used in the terminal.

```
set DB2CODEPAGE=1208
chcp 65001
db2 terminate
db2 connect to mydb

rem garbled terminal output, correct file output
db2 -r utf8.log "values U&'\0141\00F3d\017A is a city in Poland'"
echo values 'Łódź is a city in Poland' | db2 -r utf8.log +p -

rem some "translated" terminal & file output (Ł -> L, ó -> o)
db2 -r utf8.log "values 'Łódź is a city in Poland'"
```